# Rich Text area image not showing up in community

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-experience, lightning-community, richtextarea

[image]I created a lightning component,and used it in a community.Now i want to show a rich text area fields image in that component.So,for that i queried that field on opportunity object and showed the data using  aura:unescapedHtml tag on lighting component.Now the issue i am facing is,it shows me data(text) in lightning but it doesn't show image in it and gives a message "Image not Available because you don't have privileges."

Can anyone help me with this,how can i show image too?
Note:I thought this might be a access to the field issue,but i can see text data and not the image so that removes this possibility,else i wouldn't be able to see the text data i f i hadn't had the permission to see field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution to this.I stored that image in Document and copied its Id from URL and paste it into Rich Text area field.After that simply pass the id in following tag

img src="{!'/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id='+(Id from Rich text area)+'&amp oid='+(your organistaion Id)}"

Comment: How did you get image stored in document when we dont have access on "lightning:insertImageButton"

Here is the code I am using in lightning component 
<lightning:inputRichText value="<b>HELLO</b>">
        <lightning:insertImageButton/>
    </lightning:inputRichText>

Comment: Providing access to Document for Guest User helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the public URL for the image and change the source in the image tag in the rich text field in Dev console:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Thank you for including the screenshot. While screenshots are usually helpful, please also include in your post the actual text of that is visible in your screenshot - having the text only in screenshots* makes it impossible for SFSE users with screen readers to know what the text says. | *_(without alternate text)_

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by creating a sharing rule for the target object. In my case we displayed the image in public site, so I've shared it with a guest user.