# Salesforce Images from RichTextArea not being displayed in community portal

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, richtextarea

I have Salesforce custom field of RichTextArea and users are adding images in it. Now while I am displaying that field value in VF page it is not displaying the images. I found that this is happening only for my external users while they are accessing this VF page from the Salesforce community portal.

Any idea why images are not being displayed or what access rights I can provide to display images correctly.

Following is the screenshot from community portal page.
[image]

Note: I have already provided both Read and Edit rights of this field to external user's profile.

Already referred following articles but any of them did not work.

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IFQcQAO
2. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000BffHQAS
3. [Rich Text area image not showing up in community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235602/rich-text-area-image-not-showing-up-in-community)

Comment: Facing Same issue..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answer is perfectly relevant to the original issue posted here but maybe my response will help somebody.

Note that this needs to be handled on a per-image basis.

We had an Admin who was pasting images into Rich Text Components on the Homepage. It would show for the Admins, but not regular Users.

Note: Admins who logged in as regular Users WOULD see the image, but if they did a hard refresh (ctrl+F5), the "Image not available" placeholder would show.

WORKAROUND:

1. Instead of pasting the image, go to Classic and upload it to the "Documents" object, under the Public Documents folder.
2. Ensure "Externally Available Image" is enabled
3. Find the newly-uploaded file in Documents, and click "View" so the image opens in a new tab.
4. Go to where you want to add an image into a Rich Text Component.
5. From the tab opened in Step 3 with the image, DRAG the image from that tab, into the Rich Text Component.
6. Save.

Any User should be able to see the image in this component.